# Adding data from multiple columns based on comparison operators

Tags: excel, vba

I have another question. I want to know how do I retrieve data from one column and place it in another column based on comparison operators. Here is what I have so far:

Sub addcolrows()

```
Dim PTotal As Range, Shipping As Range, ShipWeight As Range, MyTotal As Range, R As Range

Set PTotal = Range("AH2:AH16254")
Set PTotalAndShipping = Range("AI2:AI16254")
Set ShipWeight = Range("U2:U16254")
Set MyTotal = Range("AJ2:AJ16254")

PTotal.Value = "=SUM(E2 + 3,)"



 For Each R In ShipWeight
 If R <= 0.16 Then
 PTotalAndShipping.Value = "=SUM(AH2 + 5, )"
 ElseIf R > 0.16 & R < 10 Then
 PTotalAndShipping.Value = "=SUM(AH2 + 10, )"
 ElseIf R > 10 & R < 20 Then
 PTotalAndShipping.Value = "=SUM(AH2 + 15, )"
 ElseIf R > 20 & R < 30 Then
 PTotalAndShipping.Value = "=SUM(AH2 + 20, )"
 ElseIf R > 30 & R < 40 Then
 PTotalAndShipping.Value = "=SUM(AH2 + 25, )"
 ElseIf R > 40 & R <= 50 Then
 PTotalAndShipping.Value = "=SUM(AH2 + 30, )"
 Else: PTotalAndShipping.Value = "=SUM(, )& "" NA """
 End If
 Next
```

End Sub

I have varying shipping weights and based on the weight classes it is desired to change data in my "PTotalAndShipping" column which is "AI". It works but the calculated numbers in the columns might be wrong and they keep flickering and my Excel application freezes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, each time you loop, you are entering the same formula in the entire column(AH)

You could return the value of R.Row then add the formula you want to PTotalAndShipping.cells(R.Row - 1, 1)

```
i = R.Row
PTotalAndShipping.cells(i - 1, 1) = "=SUM(AH" & i & + 5, )"
```

Secondly, ampersand (&) is a concatenation character. You need to use the AND keyword

```
ElseIf R > 0.16 AND R < 10 Then
```

Thirdly, you have not captured what happens if the weight is 10 (you have Less than or Greater then, but not equal to)

Lastly, to avoid screen flickering, try turning Calculation and ScreenUpdating off, just remember to switch them on again at the end of your code. You will find it best to handle this in an error handler.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

I think this should cover what you are trying to do:

```
Dim PTotal As Range, Shipping As Range, ShipWeight As Range, MyTotal As Range, R As Range, PTotalAndShipping As Range
Dim i As Long

Set PTotal = Range("AH2:AH16254")
Set PTotalAndShipping = Range("AI2:AI16254")
Set ShipWeight = Range("U2:U16254")
Set MyTotal = Range("AJ2:AJ16254")

On Error GoTo exitHere

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

PTotal.Value = "=SUM(E2 + 3,)"

For Each R In ShipWeight
i = R.Row
If R.Cells.Value <= 0.16 Then
    PTotalAndShipping.Cells(i - 1).Value = "=SUM(AH" & i & " + 5, )"
ElseIf R.Value > 0.16 And R <= 10 Then
    PTotalAndShipping.Cells(i - 1).Value = "=SUM(AH" & i & " + 10, )"
ElseIf R.Value > 10 And R <= 20 Then
    PTotalAndShipping.Cells(i - 1).Value = "=SUM(AH" & i & " + 15, )"
ElseIf R.Value > 20 And R <= 30 Then
    PTotalAndShipping.Cells(i - 1).Value = "=SUM(AH" & i & " + 20, )"
ElseIf R.Value > 30 And R <= 40 Then
    PTotalAndShipping.Cells(i - 1).Value = "=SUM(AH" & i & " + 25, )"
ElseIf R.Value > 40 And R <= 50 Then
    PTotalAndShipping.Cells(i - 1).Value = "=SUM(AH" & i & " + 30, )"
Else: PTotalAndShipping.Cells(i - 1).Value = "=SUM(, )& "" NA """
End If
Next

exitHere:

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

This is just a quick attempt to get your current code working, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It works!!! Great!!! And may I ask if you believe I optimized the code well enough?

Comment: Using the Sum formula and everything else?